# IEEEtran: Placing a two-column figure on desired page

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column, ieeetran

Using the `IEEEtran` class, I have problems positioning a two-column figure on the desired page: The figure is always plotted on the next page.

Here my minimal code:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Conclusion}
\label{sec:EndConclusion}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Conclusion text

\begin{figure*}[tb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figure1}
\caption{caption}
\end{figure*}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{bibliography} 

\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image]

I'd like to have the figure on the top and then **Conclusion** and **References** below. There is definitely enough space for everything. What can I do?

Well, my real conclusion is longer, and I have more bib entries, then the references should continue on the next page.

Comment: Don't use identifiers such as `[tb]` with starred figure environment.

Comment: @percusse, but how else should I declare where I want my figure?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314257/time-travel-in-latex

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Next paragraph appears in page 11 from [`IEEEtran_HOWTO`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ieeetran)

> Another `LATEX2ε` limitation (patched with stfloats or not) is that
>   double column floats will not appear on the same page where they are
>   defined. So, the user will have to define such things prior to the
>   page on which they are to (possibly) appear.

So if you want that your figure be placed where Conclusions and References, declare it in previous page. And remember that due to next paragraph (page 9)

> Furthermore, IEEE journals never place floats in the first column of
>   the first page and rarely (if ever) do they do so in the second column
>   of the first page. Middle in-text placement (“here”) is not used.

you must test it with enough text to fill more than one page, otherwise your figure will always appear on an empty second page.

Comment: This is an explanation of why it behaves as described in the problem, but it isn't a solution.

Comment: @stefanct The solution consists in declaring the double column float in previous page. If you know a better solution, please, write it.

Comment: And since there is no notation of "pages" within latex, i.e. one cannot simply detect where a page ends, and even then it would be hard to insert the float before that point this is a rather convoluted problem as can be seen in the linked SA thread that *does* give solutions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314257/time-travel-in-latex If I'd knew a better solution I would have posted it of course.

Answer (score 12):

```
This worked for me  

\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/classifiers-boxplot.png}
    \caption{}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Did you read the comments below the question? I am not familiar with this environment, but it seems manual placement is discouraged.

Comment: You saved my Day! Thanks