# Placing a figure in the bottom of a page spanning the two columns of an IEEE document

Tags: graphics, floats, ieeetran

I am writing an `IEEEtran` article. I use `graphicx` for inserting `.pdf` images. Normally, LaTeX selects a position like A. I want LaTeX automatically find and insert the image to a position like B. How can I do that? This is my code:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \includegraphics{Figures/Fig1.pdf}\\
  \caption{hi}\label{hi}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: <<There is no bottom area for page-wide floats in two-column mode>> from http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat?lq=1

Comment: @touhami So we can't do this in LaTeX?

Comment: @user2991243 - What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: @AboAmmar `\documentclass[conference,hidelinks]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: @user2991243 - Please see my answer.

Comment: For a figure just use \begin{figure}[b]

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You need to use the starred version of the `{figure*}` environment to enable the figure occupy the two columns. Besides, you also need to load the `dblfloatfix` package (download from [here](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dblfloatfix)), which is necessary for placing the figure in the bottom of the page. It allows you the use either of the options `[tbp]`. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[conference,hidelinks]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}    % To enable figures at the bottom of page
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % [demo] option for empty figure
\usepackage{kantlipsum}     % for random text

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\kant[1-5]
\begin{figure*}[!b]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{MyFigure}
    \caption{My Figure in Two Columns}
\end{figure*}
\kant[6-11]
\end{document}
```

Which outputs the following:

[image]

Comment: Be aware that as explained in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153850/placing-a-two-column-figure-using-ieeetran-class, you may need to declare your figure prior to where you want it to be placed.

Comment: What is the difference between figure and figure*?

Comment: @pitosalas it lets the figure span both columns

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
test
\end{multicols}
\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{Figures/Fig1.pdf}\\
  \caption{hi}\label{hi}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi you, dear downvoter, please before downvote can you be more helpfull and leave a comment?  I don't remember that my answer was so bad in 2000(15).

Comment: I did not downvote, but in general on stackExchange pages, you should explain in words what your code does and why it does do what it does.
For example, what does `[htp]` mean in your snippet, where is it defined, etc.?
Also: How can I use width and bottom placement in one command (you provided neither of them in your snippet)?