# How do I place a figure* environment after a balanced bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, floats, two-column

I have a two-column paper. The structure is the following:

```
\documentclass[conference, letterpaper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
\title{mytitle}
\thanks{}
\author{}
\maketitle

% .. many sections

{
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\balance\bibliography{ref}
}

% big figure here
\begin{figure*}
\end{figure*}
```

The problem is that the figure is moved in a new page although there is a lot of space after the references. I tried many things, like using the package "flushend" etc, but I can't achieve what I would like: I want balanced references in the last page (at the top) with a figure* at the bottom in the same page.

Comment: [Placing a figure in the bottom of a page spanning the two columns of an IEEE document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235623/134144) might be interesting.

Comment: `IEEEtran` has its own method for manually balance a bibliography, through `\IEEEtriggeratref{<n>}`, where `<n>` stands for the first bibliography item that should appear in the second column. In any case, both `\balance` (that requires a package you're not showing) and the manual method can only work if they force a page break at the end of the bibliography and the figure will go to the next page nonetheless.

Comment: Why not put the figure* before the bibliography?  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/531802?r=SearchResults&s=4|17.0199#531802

Comment: I used the solution below. Thanks also to @egreg who actually taught me LaTeX in a class I took at the University of Verona!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try along these lines:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,...]{...}
\usepackage{stfloats} % two column float locations
...
\begin{document}
lots of two column text
\begin{figure*}[b] % put at bottom of page
the graphic
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

See the `stfloats` package documentation for more details (`texdoc stfloats`).

Comment: Yes, this solved the issue. Thank you!