# Full width figures at bottom of first page of two column document

Tags: floats, positioning, two-column

I know this has been asked before. There are many questions where the solution is to use the `dblfloatfix` package. However, the MWE below creates a document where the figure is on the bottom of page 2. All the solutions I find are resolved by including the package and using `[!b]`, perhaps something has been updated since those solutions were made.

See for example this solution:
[Placing a figure in the bottom of a page spanning the two columns of an IEEE document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235623/placing-a-figure-in-the-bottom-of-a-page-spanning-the-two-columns-of-an-ieee-doc)
Using the same method no longer works, the figure appears at the bottom of the second page.

Here is my MWE. I am on Arch Linux with the latest version of everything (I updated before creating the question just in case).

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[!b]
  \includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{MyFigure}
  \caption{Hoping for this to appear at the bottom of the first page}
\end{figure*}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Right after I finish whining about it, I solve my problem. Using the package `nidanfloat` accomplishes the task. I wouldn't mind hearing some insight into how the `nidanfloat` and `dblfloatfix` packages operate differently though.