# Stop the table from moving to the next page

Tags: tables, formatting

This question is redundant but I really don't know how to fix my code! In my following code, I want to span the table over the two-column paper format. However, the table moves to the next page!! How can I stop that and make it at the top of the same page?

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}


\begin{document}


\section{Results}

\begin{table*}[!t]
\centering
\caption{Results} \label{xor-table}

\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Approach}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{\parbox[c]{2mm}{\multirow{2}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Metric}}}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{XOR Gate}}\\ \cline{3-6} 
&& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Positive \end{tabular}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Negative\end{tabular}}} \\ \cline{3-6} 
&& \textbf{K=512}& \textbf{K=1024}& \textbf{K=512}& \textbf{K=1024}\\  \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}


\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Method\\ A \end{tabular}}}
&$k$\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} &512&1024&512&1024 \\ \cline{2-6} 
& \emph{S} &&&& \\ \cline{2-6} 
& $T$(s) &&& &\\ \Xhline{2\arrayrulewidth}

\multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Method\\ B \end{tabular}}} 
&$k$\tnote{\textasteriskcentered} &512 &1024&512&1024\\ \cline{2-6} 
& \emph{S}  &&&& \\ \cline{2-6} 
& $T$(s) & &&& \\ \hline


\end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
    \item[\textasteriskcentered] The number of partitions 
    \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: if something is already set on a two-column page, it is impossible to set a full-width float at the top of the page.  the input for the float should be positioned before the start of the page on which it is to appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package `placeins` has macro `\FloatBarrier` to prevent floats from moving too far.

Comment: But why does it happen in the first place? Here's a MWE that is typeset as two pages: `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\begin{document}

Results

\begin{table*}
    K
\end{table*}

\end{document}
`

Comment: This depends on the parameters of the float placement algorithm.

Comment: I realized it's because of the two-column layout, where [`table*`](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-widefigs.html) means span both columns, and [“the only available options are `t` (top of next page) or `p` (end of document)”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89462/page-wide-table-in-two-column-mode). And according to IEEEtran, [“double column floats will not appear on the same page where they are defined. So, the user will have to define such things prior to the page on which they are to (possibly) appear”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153859/48).

Comment: `placeins` with `IEEEtran`'s double-column floats wrecks havoc (the text output is stopped at the place of `\FloatBarrier` and blank space is inserted until after the figure... which still gets rendered on the following page no matter what.