# Putting two figures side by side shifts them on to a new page?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, minipage, subfig

In two-column paper I want to place two figures side by side. If I use `figure*` it shifts them to a new page. If I use `minipage` option again figures don't obtain correct position. Can I fix this problem using `figure*`?

Here is my code that I am using. My figures are moving to next page that I don't want. Please guide me how to fix this problem?

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \begin{minipage}[l]{1.0\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{Hist_J_0/hist_h1.PNG}
        \caption{}
    end{minipage}
    \hfill{}
    \begin{minipage}[r]{1.0\columnwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{Hist_J_0/hist_h5.PNG}
        \caption{}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Welcome. Could you please add a compilable example?

Comment: Actually I am new on this forum. I just want to to know how to fix position of two subfigurs  in two column paper .In my case I want to show the result on page 1 but it moves to the page two. Is there any way to fix figures on the top or bottom of the page using figure*  environment

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. A `figure*` environment should be used only if (a) the document is in two-column mode and (b) you need the contents of the environment to span the width of both columns. By default, `figure*` and `table*` environments are always placed at the top of a page. If you plan to place 2 subfigures side-by-side inside a single `figure` (or `figure*`) environment, you should look into the capabilities of the `subfig` and `subcaption` packages. This site has lots of queries related to exactly this topic.

Comment: I want to place two subfigure side by side in two coloums in a two-column page

Comment: @jerry Without an example code we can do nothing, because basically we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jerry - Do please search this site for queries about the two issues raised by your query.

Comment: I already searched and try to implemented. But still figures are moving to next page

Comment: May be this helps: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153859/1952

Comment: @jerry - Have you searched this site for applications of the `stfloats` package?

Comment: No I have searched it using dblfloatfix, figure* and minipage environment

Comment: `figure*` always comes at the earliest on teh next page, so simply move it earlier in the source so it gets typeset on the page that you want,.

Comment: typeset ? can you please explain it bit more

Comment: @jerry: Could you please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages?

Comment: I've closed this posting as a duplicate of an earlier one. The earlier posting refers to `table*` environments, but it's applicable to `figure*` environments as well.

Answer (score 2):

As David Carlisle told you, a `figure*` is always placed on page following the page where it is declared on `.tex` file. Therefore even if you start your document with `\begin{figure*}`, the figure will appear on second page.

This is the normal behaviour, but Mico proposed to use `stfloats` package which solves the problem.

Following Mico's suggestion, please note that `l` and `r` positioning parameters are not valid for `minipage`. Only top `t`, center `c` and bottom `b` are accepted.

As your figures are declared into a `minipage`, `\linewidth` value adjusts to `minipage` size, therefore you could also use `width=...\linewidth` in `includegraphics` parameters.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\begin{document}
     \begin{figure*}[b]
        \begin{minipage}{1.0\columnwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
        \end{minipage}
        \hfill  %<-- changed from \hfill{}. See David's comment
        \begin{minipage}{1.0\columnwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{example-image-b}
            \caption{}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure*}

\lipsum[1-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please also inform the OP that the `minipage` environment does *not* recognize `l` and `r` as positioning specifiers; the only recognized specifiers are `t` (top), `c`(center -- the default), and `b` (bottom). Also, the `\centering` instructions are redundant since the images take up the full width of the column.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for pointing it, I didn't notice. About `\centering` command, it was my fault because I changed original `7.5cm` to `\linewidth`,

Comment: `\end{minipage}
        \hfill{}
        \begin`  only works if `\columnsep` is more than two word spaces, better to use `\end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin` or the images could be set vertically rather than side by side.